# Como usar una variable fuera del use effect en react js con firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Necesito usar la constante arreglo fuera del `use effect`, si bien la declaro antes, cuando la quiero usar fuera sigue vacia y solo tiene datos dentro cuando lo muestro por consola dentro del `use effect`.

Necesito usar esa variable fuera para poder utilizarla al renderizar el componente.

```
const arreglo = []

useEffect(() => {

const getProductos = async () => {
  const querySnapshot = await db.collection(`categoria/${categoria}/polera`).get();
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc =>{
    const prod = doc.data()
    arreglo.push(prod)
  })
  console.log(arreglo)
  
} 

getProductos()

});
```

Comment: ¿Y por qué no declarar el arreglo dentro del `useEffect` y luego pasarlo a un estado? Así podrías usar su contenido en cualquier parte del componente.

Answer (score 0):

En React se usan **[estados](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)** para manejar la información de los componentes. Entonces si necesitas obtener información de alguna `API`, debes *setear* el `state` con el response de dicho servicio.

```
const [arreglo, setArreglo] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
   //... llamada asíncrona
   const list = querySnapshot.map(item => ({ prod: item.data }))
   setArreglo(list)
}, [])
```

y después para renderizar...

```
return 
   <>
      {arreglo.map((item, index) => (
         <code key={index}>{item}</code>
         <br />
       ))}
   </>
```

Como primera observación, si necesitas obtener información de esa `API` sólo en un componente, procura especificar como segundo parámetro del **[useEffect](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)**, los corchetes vacíos, lo que indica que sólo se ejecutara al entrar a dicho componente. Si no le especificas el segundo parámetro, habrá renderizaciones con cada interacción y afectará la performance del aplicativo.

Y segundo es que cambie tu loop, por la función **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** de `JavaScript` que te obtiene el mismo resultado de una forma más limpia.

Cualquier duda acá estaremos. Nos comentas si te sirvió :D